# Why doesn't RTSP (sdp) Quicktime embed work in FF and IE?

Tags: embed, quicktime, rtsp, sdp

I have an embed code that plays streaming video:

```
<object width="640" height="480" id="qt" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
<param name="src" value="MY STREAM URL">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="controller" value="false">
<embed id="plejer" name="plejer" src="/poster.mov" bgcolor="000000" width="640" height="480" scale="ASPECT" qtsrc="MY STREAM URL" href="MY STREAM URL"  kioskmode="true" showlogo=false" autoplay="true" controller="false" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
</embed></object>
```

The embed works as expected in Chrome. However in FireFox(3.6) and IE(9) I get a quicktime logo. I've checked my quicktime player prefs and I don't see a streaming or sdp option in the mime options.

Any ideas why I'm seeing this issue?

Comment: Your `embed` tag is set up to initially display a "poster" video (at `/poster.mov`, and then change to the stream when its clicked on. The `object` tag isn't (and also skips many of the parameters you're including in the embed). The general idea with these `embed` inside `object` schemes (particularly with QuickTime) is to pass the same parameters in both tags, the `object` covering IE, the `embed` covering basically everybody else.

Comment: thanks, got it working. Firefox is still an issue. However, I only need it to work in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your embed tag is set up to initially display a "poster" video (at /poster.mov, and then change to the stream when its clicked on. The object tag isn't (and also skips many of the parameters you're including in the embed). The general idea with these embed inside object schemes (particularly with QuickTime) is to pass the same parameters in both tags, the object covering IE, the embed covering basically everybody else. – John Flatness